# Reference for Wasserstein distance for generalized exponential family and generalized extreme value probability distributions

Tags: distributions, wasserstein

The Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) gives the analytical results for computing the Wasserstein metric between two multivariate normal distributions, and I thought it used to give results for several other commonly applied parametric distribution families, but now I cannot find them. Can someone suggest a reference document which has collected all of the analytical results for how to easily compute (ideally in closed form) the Wasserstein distance between two univariate distributions within the same family? I'm particularly interested in results for generalized extreme value distributions (e.g. Weibull, Frechet, etc.) and also exponential family distributions (e.g. Gamma, Poisson, etc.). Thanks in advance.